# ECDH nodejs and C# key exchange

Tags: c#, node.js, cryptography, ecdh

I've lost my self and I need help to go in the right direction :) 
I have nodejs server that have to exchange some critical data with the server that is written in C#, so in that case, I want my data to be encrypted somehow. I was thinking about AES, and to safely exchange keys i want to use ECDH but I don't know how to make it work correctly... If I'm thinking right way I can make my C# "allice" side like this :

```
ECDiffieHellman alice = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP192t1);
var aliceKey = alice.PublicKey;
var ketyToExport = Convert.ToBase64String(aliceKey.ToByteArray());
//send ketyToExport to nodejs
//KEY FROM nodejs
var key1 = Convert.FromBase64String("BIzSJ1dmTXpSS8rqkVFISZ+vumhqXYMWfWoU5vB9GHhOtxxDInu/GZ92VJpqhrE3vw==").ToList();
var keyType = new byte[] { 0x45, 0x43, 0x4B, 0x31 };
var keyLength = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
key1.RemoveAt(0);
key1 = keyType.Concat(keyLength).Concat(key1).ToList();
byte[] bobKeyBytes = key1.ToArray();
//and I have a problem with that line bellow, I do not know how to make it work
var aliceSecret = alice.DeriveKeyMaterial(/*ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey bobKeyBytes*/);
```

And nodejs "Bob" side like this:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const bob = crypto.createECDH('brainpoolP192t1')
const bobKey = bob.generateKeys('base64');
var bobLength = Buffer.from(bobKey, 'base64').length;
//send bobkey to c#
//recive alicekey
var tmp = "RUNLUBgAAAAR9C7kO2o+vxNT/UBvvEuJHNdI8NfU4fUxUT431ER1q3kJbeUVHepoG5SWUM2NHj8="
var aliceKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(tmp, 'base64');
var aliceKey = Buffer.alloc(bobLength)
aliceKeyBuffer.copy(aliceKey, 1, 8);
aliceKey[0] = 4;
bob.computeSecret(aliceKey);
//create aes 
//get mesage and iv ...
```

Okay so I've made some adjustments to all of that but right now I don't know what to do about this line how to make it work... 
`var aliceSecret = alice.DeriveKeyMaterial(/*ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey bobKeyBytes*/);`

**#BIG EDIT** 
I got help in [ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey from ByteArray (using ECDiffieHellman NamedCurves)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591471/ecdiffiehellmanpublickey-from-bytearray-using-ecdiffiehellman-namedcurves/)
and now I have another problem -_- 
my node js code didn't change from above but c# looks like:

```
using (ECDiffieHellman alice = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP256r1))
{
    var alicePublicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(alice.PublicKey.ToByteArray());
    //NODEJS brainpoolP256r1 publickey 
    var key1 = Convert.FromBase64String("BASsbkule53ARqlMBA8hYysyyoRi3xGxGnSzIJ2fS5FlLniQD/zYiiGUVydmO/BBkQwVTUo5f4OMCxVNtQ/LuMQ=");
    byte[] keyX = new byte[key1.Length / 2];
    byte[] keyY = new byte[keyX.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(key1, 1, keyX, 0, keyX.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(key1, 1 + keyX.Length, keyY, 0, keyY.Length);
    ECParameters parameters = new ECParameters
    {
        Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP256r1,
        Q =
        {
            X = keyX,
            Y = keyY,
        },
    };
    byte[] derivedKey;
    using (ECDiffieHellman bob = ECDiffieHellman.Create(parameters))
    using (ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey bobPublic = bob.PublicKey)
    {
        derivedKey = alice.DeriveKeyFromHash(bobPublic, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    }
    var aliceKey = Convert.ToBase64String(derivedKey);
    byte[] encryptedMessage = null;
    byte[] iv = null;
    // Send(aliceKey, "Secret message", out encryptedMessage, out iv);
}
```

and it is working but it gives me different secret keys ... 
out of `bob.computeSecret(aliceKey)` i got `iIoH9aJoWf3666QQ6X+kj4iUKrk9j+hbRuXbhgs7YzM=`
and out of `alice.DeriveKeyFromHash(bobPublic, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);`
I got `wJ7O4Hm2Jxs1FcLx6KaMmENvqdTQJPZ/YNSs1+MQDOQ=`
if I'm thinking correctly they should be equal. am I thinking wrong?

**#EDIT DONE !!**

So this adding this code on end of js file gave me what I needed.

```
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
var tt = bob.computeSecret(aliceKey);
hash.update(tt);
console.log(hash.digest('base64'));
```

Comment: You should be using SSL/TLS. Every software environment that matters supports it.

Comment: I got a restriction for not to use ssl/tls ... another option that I have is to write node native addon in C++ that will support RSA encryption and some weird stuff that was written more than 10 y ago that contains "magicInt" and "magicIntArray" that is like a packet of data it contains the header, info about data and data. and is based on shifting some bytes and playing around with streams...

But if I could use SSL/TSL it would be easy as starting https on C# server because communication is based on JSON-RPC and http server is running...

Comment: Usually the public keys are encoded as uncompressed points (starting with a byte valued `04` followed by a statically sized X and Y, both 24 bytes. How you transfer the public key value is up to you. If you have just a socket you can stick to binary, no need for encoding / decoding.

Comment: Okey. I have computeSecred in node but I have a problem with c# 
added info to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**##SOLUTION##**

**C#**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ECDiffieHellman alice = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP256r1))
        {
            var alicePublicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(alice.PublicKey.ToByteArray());
            //send alicePublicKey
            var nodejsKey = ""; //NODEJS brainpoolP256r1 publickey  base64
            byte[] nodejsKeyBytes= Convert.FromBase64String(nodejsKey);

            var aliceKey = Convert.ToBase64String(getDeriveKey(nodejsKeyBytes,alice));
            byte[] encryptedMessage = null;
            byte[] iv = null;
            // Send(aliceKey, "Secret message", out encryptedMessage, out iv);
        }
    }
    static byte[] getDeriveKey(byte[] key1, ECDiffieHellman alice)
    {
        byte[] keyX = new byte[key1.Length / 2];
        byte[] keyY = new byte[keyX.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(key1, 1, keyX, 0, keyX.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(key1, 1 + keyX.Length, keyY, 0, keyY.Length);
        ECParameters parameters = new ECParameters
        {
            Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.brainpoolP256r1,
            Q =
            {
                X = keyX,
                Y = keyY,
            },
        };
        byte[] derivedKey;
        using (ECDiffieHellman bob = ECDiffieHellman.Create(parameters))
        using (ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey bobPublic = bob.PublicKey)
        {
            return derivedKey = alice.DeriveKeyFromHash(bobPublic, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
        }
    }
}
```

**NODEJS**

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const bob = crypto.createECDH('brainpoolP256r1')
bob.generateKeys();
const bobKey = bob.getPublicKey('base64');
var bobLength = Buffer.from(bobKey, 'base64').length;
//send bobkey to c#
//recive alicekey

var alicePublicKey = "RUNLUCAAAAB/xP7JhSIhYIYAijyC2zHu7obB5CwfK/ynQPxcRAIhBI6OLRRcHyPo61AhfSZN3qA2vGDfWO2mrdWWvqqhVaDf";
var aliceKeyBuffer = Buffer.from(alicePublicKey, 'base64');
var aliceKey = Buffer.alloc(bobLength)
aliceKeyBuffer.copy(aliceKey, 1, 8);
aliceKey[0] = 4;
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
var tt = bob.computeSecret(aliceKey);
var bobSecretKey = hash.update(tt).digest('base64');
```

big thanks for [@bartonjs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6535399/bartonjs) and [@Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/maarten-bodewes)

Answer (score 1):

The above answer helped me a lot. I am using `secp521r1`/`nistP521` to do the key generation in both NodeJS and C#. In my case, a call to `alice.PublicKey.ToByteArray()` would result in an exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellmanImplementation.ECDiffieHellmanSecurityTransforms.ECDiffieHellmanSecurityTransformsPublicKey.ToByteArray()
```

According to an issue logged with the dotnet runtime team [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27276):

> ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey.ToByteArray() doesn't have a (standards-)defined export format. The version used by ECDiffieHellmanPublicKeyCng is Windows-specific, and only works for NIST P-256 (secp256r1), NIST P-384 (secp384r1), and NIST P-521 (secp521r1).
>
> To create a copy of a key you should use the ExportParameters() method to obtain the rich ECParameters object; which can then be sent through ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECParameters) and the PublicKey property of that object be read to get back a second instance of ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey.

Assuming I send my X and Y from Alice to Bob (I used hex instead of base64), the corresponding process to arrive at the same shared secret on the NodeJS side looks like this:

```
// Alice's public key X, Y coordinates from DotNet Core
const aliceHexX = '00248F624728B17196B22005742C13D80D3DFF75BCA74AF865195E5A29F41C013653B0931BC544245402EDD7922F38692F38DCCF780CF1A9E27D3CFB5E09E53883C0';
const aliceHexY = '0043517F3B2EF33ED70EFA2BC4163E9B99558A7C2ECB7C659A12EA4024633CFA8B9FC997F0A42D30759B4280FDADC13A67A3E7BB0227047C907FAAE92E7716E8A10D';

const alicePublicKeyXBytes = Buffer.from(aliceHexX, 'hex');
const alicePublicKeyYBytes = Buffer.from(aliceHexY, 'hex');
const alicePublicKey = Buffer.concat([Buffer.from([0x04]), alicePublicKeyXBytes, alicePublicKeyYBytes])
const bobSecret = bob.computeSecret(alicePublicKey);

const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
hash.update(bobSecret);
const sharedSecret = hash.digest('hex');
console.log(`Shared Secret: ${sharedSecret.toString('hex')}`);
```